# Control RS-232 device with no control software avalible

Tags: serial-port, hardware

I bought an hdmi switch which has a rs-232 serial port to control input and output.
The problem is that I don't have software to use that interface and no expirience programing with it.
The only thing I have is a page of documentation about the the port on the switch.
[documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMbr.png)
I tried using that information by typing some of the codes into a serial debugger. Obviously I had no luck with my attempt due to no expirience with the serial port.
I hope someone can help me understanding the documentation.
Thanks in advance RedCrafter_LP.

Comment: *"Control RS-232 device with no driver avalible"* -- That's a misleading, as the *"driver"* is part of the OS.  What you *"tried"* is not clear or detailed.  You can either write a program to send the commands, or translate the hex values to ASCII keystrokes and send using a terminal emulation program.  E.G. `0x04` is `ctrl D`, `0x55` is `U`, `0x20` is ` ` (space), and `0x77` is `w`, which comprises the first command listed.

Comment: @sawdust Sorry for the misleading title I was unshure how to call my problem. Would "... with no control software" be better? I don't quite get the second part, my problem is that i'm unable to "send" the commands given in the documentation correctly probably due to wrong code I send. Do you understand the documentation if so please help me undertand the meaning of it.

Comment: The first column of that chart contains commands listed as 4- or 5-byte sequences.  Each byte is represented as a 2-digit hexadecimal number.  Each byte (i.e. the numeric value) also represents an [ASCII code](https://theasciicode.com.ar/), for either a printable character or a control character.  Both [printable](http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php) and [control characters](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php) can be entered/typed through a PC keyboard and then sent out the serial port using a *terminal emulation program*, e.g. **Putty**, **Teraterm**, or **minicom**.

Comment: Therefore each byte of a command sequence can be entered/typed/sent using a terminal emulation program.

Comment: I tried to use putty and Teraterm but both just showed blank terminals and i couldn't type in anything. Am I doing something wrong? I'm using a usb serial adapter btw could it be the cause? Should I restart after connecting it?

Comment: *"... just showed blank terminals and i couldn't type in anything'* -- Just because you see nothing does not mean what you type is not transmitted.  Only devices or servers that interact with humans (are configured to) echo back the input.  Programs tend to be simplistic, don't need the feedback of echo, and don't want to receive what was transmitted.  So either blindly type the characters, or enable local echo.  The ability to display control characters is yet another configuration option.